# Genymotion Desktop is stuck on "booting" status

Tags: genymotion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tffuQ.png)

I installed  genymotin  but it  stuck on "booting" status
I unistalled and re_installed genymotion and virtualbox and uninstalled/purge too like this link https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177

but it dosent work ?

sorry for my english

Comment: Do you have virtualization enabled on BIOS settings? and it may take time and may need more waiting

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. Please see our sister network https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reinstall genymotion and virtualbox, you must first disconnect the Windows Internet connection, then install the two programs, then connect the Internet for login